# Trying to get permutations of 3 seperate integers that equal a particular sum. New to programming

Tags: c++

```
// This program gives the possible combination of power
// distributor settings after giving it one of the variables.
// EG: sys=0>>> will return one option of eng=4 wep=8 for macro creations.
//
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

    int sys[9] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};
    int eng[9] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};
    int wep[9] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};

class power
{
    public:
        char sys;
        char eng;
        char wep;
};
```

What I'm trying to accomplish is to take one value from each of the different arrays and find all the permutations that equal 12. EX: sys[3]+eng[5]+wep[7]=12. I would like to do this by being able to enter in 1 of the known values eg sys[3] and have it tell me the other possible values from the two other sections, but have no clue where to start, all the permutation code strings I have come across I was unable to tailor to my specific needs and have reached a roadblock, this is just a for fun thing but would really like to figure it out.

Comment: Forget about C++ for a moment. Sit down, and write an outline on a piece of paper, in plain English, of an algorithm that you think will implement this. Then, [explain your algorithm to your rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging). Once your rubber duck agrees with your approach, right in front of you will be a detailed explanation, in plain English, that can be directly translated into code. Good luck.

Comment: in your example sys[3]+eng[5]+wep[7] is 15 not 12

Comment: also if you don't have performance requirement then a quick solution is just brute force search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My rubber duck said to use 3 nested loops .
Each loop steps through one of the arrays. In the innermost loop add the three values and compare to 12.

Comment: sam's comment made me sit down and think about it a little more, and shortly before your post I had come to the conclusion to use loops to achieve my goal, thanks to your post you have explained a better use than what I had originally come up with. Thanks and I will post the finished product when done so if someone else has this problem there will be a reference.

Comment: Quack! Quack! Quack!

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how many times the calculation is done on the same data type, there may be better solutions.

Another less brute force method is to generate tables for all combinations of two variables, sort and save it, so that the calculation can be done with a binary search, then the complexity of each call is reduced from O(mn) to O(log(mn)).

This could be easily implemented using `std::map` or `std::unordered_map`.

Here's a brief example that implements the case where `sum` and `wep` is known and to calculate `sys` and `eng`.

The `Table` class can be reused for other two cases.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

// This program gives the possible combination of power
// distributor settings after giving it one of the variables.
// EG: sys=0>>> will return one option of eng=4 wep=8 for macro creations.
//
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <map>
#include <utility>

using namespace std;

    int sys[9] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};
    int eng[9] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};
    int wep[9] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};

class Table
{
public:
    Table(int *a, int *b, size_t size)
    {
        for(size_t i=0;i<size;i++){
            for(size_t j=0;j<size;j++){
                table[a[i]+b[j]] = std::pair<int, int>(a[i], b[j]);
            }
        }
    }
    bool find(const int sum, const int other,
          int *first, int *second)
    {
        bool ret;
        std::pair<int, int> lookedUp = table[sum-other];
        ret = lookedUp.first||lookedUp.second;
        if(ret){
            *first = lookedUp.first;
            *second = lookedUp.second;
        }else{
            table.erase(sum-other);
        }
        return ret;
    }
private:
    std::map<int, std::pair<int, int> > table;
};


int main() {
    Table t1(sys, eng, 9);
    int sys, eng;
    if(t1.find(12, 8, &sys, &eng)){
        cout << "for sum=12, wep=8, found " <<"sys=" <<sys << " "<< "eng=" << eng;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The problem of this approach is that it can not handle the data set whose members can be 0, because then `std::map` can not distinguish whether it's a failed look-up or a successful look-up with return value (0,0).

If you work exclusively with unsigned data sets then this could be addressed by adding a constant to the data set so that valid data is never 0.

Demo:
   https://ideone.com/JwP15r